# Getting the two letter language code of the client

Tags: python, django

This is probably a very common question but after a lot of Googling, I'm still yet to find a useful answer.

My site is only in English but I like to keep logs of the user's sessions and I need to get the client's language. I've read that I can get the the language information from the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header which is a comma-separated list of the client's languages in a descending order of priority i.e. the first one is the primary language.

I'd like to get the two-letter language code of the client's language in Django. e.g.

```
en-gb, en-us                       en
fr-fr, en-au                       fr
zh, en-us; q=0.8, en; q=0.6       zh
```

How can I do this? Do I have to parse the header myself or does Django have a inbuilt list of languages?

Is there detailed list of all the language codes?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought that too but I wanted to double-check whether it is a reliable method for accomplishing what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `translation.get_language_from_request` :

```
from django.utils import translation

def view(request):

    client_lang = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
```

By the way why you want this ? did you check django support for [i18n and l10n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/), because
if you have the `LocaleMiddleware` enable you can also get the language using `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`.

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing as `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` -- it's the language they're using to view your site, not the preferred language of their browser, isn't it?